# How to express a escape sequence in regex. ("" -> ")

Tags: regex

It's a question in Engineering a Compiler. 2.3.2

In PL/I, we can insert a quotation mark into a string by writing two quotation marks in a row.

For example, we write "This is a quotation mark, "", do you see that?" as a string and the output should be

This is a quotation mark, ", do you see that?

So, I'm trouble in writing a regex to express this sentence.

Comment: Can you give examples of working/not working sentences

Comment: parser would treat `"This is a quotion mark, "` and `", do you see that?"` as separate.

Comment: I'm not clear why you're using regexen for this, but, like Amir, I think some examples of things the pattern should match/not match from sample text would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a regex that matches string literals, or do you want a regex that replaces `""` with `"`?

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous words. It's just a easy question writing a regex to express a string parttern. And in this kind of string, using double quotation marks to insert a quotation. In the example I gave, the output of this string is - This is a quotation mark, ", do you see that? Have I expressed clearly?

Comment: The quote characters have no special meaning in regex - they do not need escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most uncertainty about what you want comes from you stating *"writing a regex to express this sentence"* and *"a regex to express a string pattern"*. Regexes express string patterns, that's what they do, that's what they are, (regular) **expressions**. If you want a regex to ***match*** a quoted string and accept two quotes as content within the string rather than the beginning/end of the string, this would be a way to do it:

```
"(?:[^"]|"")*"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/23Zt6HtJK88p5lbV)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Sorry for my humble embrassing words.